# Using opencv to mask the background

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to use tesseract to read text from a game with poor results.

What I would like to accomplish is to remove the background from the image so that only the text is visible to improve OCR results.

I've tried cv2.inRange, thresholding yet I can't seem to get it to work.

````
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, OEM

def _img_to_bytes(image: np.ndarray, colorspace: str = 'LAB'):
    # Sets an OpenCV-style image for recognition: https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/198
    bytes_per_pixel = image.shape[2] if len(image.shape) == 3 else 1
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    bytes_per_line = bytes_per_pixel * width
    if bytes_per_pixel != 1 and colorspace != 'RGB':
        # non-RGB color image -> convert to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, getattr(cv2, f'COLOR_{colorspace}2RGB'))
    elif bytes_per_pixel == 1 and image.dtype == bool:
        # binary image -> convert to bitstream
        image = np.packbits(image, axis=1)
        bytes_per_line = image.shape[1]
        width = bytes_per_line * 8
        bytes_per_pixel = 0
    # else image already RGB or grayscale
    return image.tobytes(), width, height, bytes_per_pixel, bytes_per_line

img = cv2.imread("ref.png")
img = ~img



clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3., tileGridSize=(8,8))

lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

l2 = clahe.apply(l)

lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b))
img = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

with PyTessBaseAPI(psm=3, oem=OEM.LSTM_ONLY, path=f"ocr", lang=d2r ) as api:
    api.ReadConfigFile("ocr/config.txt")
    api.SetVariable("user_words_file","ocr/dict.txt")

    api.SetImageBytes(*_img_to_bytes(img))

    print(api.GetUTF8Text())



cv2.imshow('res',img)
cv2.waitKey()```
````

Answer (score -1):

Inverting color may help? try this & let me know.

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("Bytelock.jpg")
image = ~image
cv2.imwrite("Bytelock.jpg",image)
```

Inverted image

[image]

Red varient

```
import numpy as np
import imutils

import cv2

img_rgb = cv2.imread('ss.jpg')

Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img_rgb[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]

cv2.imshow("red", img_rgb)
cv2.imwrite("red.jpg", img_rgb)
```

[image]

More sharpen? Try

```
import numpy as np
import imutils

import cv2

img_rgb = cv2.imread('ss.jpg')

Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img_rgb[mask == 255] = [0, 0, 255]


cv2.imwrite("mask.jpg", mask)


cv2.imshow("mask", mask)  # show windows

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

**

## Much more better option

**

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("ss1.jpg")
image = ~image


img = image



clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3., tileGridSize=(8,8))

lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  

l2 = clahe.apply(l)  

lab = cv2.merge((l2,a,b)) 
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  
cv2.imshow('Increased contrast', img2)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

More sharpen

[image]

Comment: Sadly the results are still poor... I've added the code snippet in my question.

Comment: inverting doesn't change the data in any meaningful ways. any thresholding still behaves the same.

Comment: what about extracting the writings colors (there should'nt be that many and they're always the same) and thresholding for that ?